# Python django writing ascii characters in coded format in file

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to generate the `abc.tex` file
I am displaying the the data in browser and same data i am writing to tex file like this

```
with open("sample.tex") as f:
    t = Template(f.read())

head = ['name','class']
c = Context({"head":headers, "table": rowlist})

# Render template
output = t.render(c)

with open("mytable.tex", 'w') as out_f:
    out_f.write(output)
```

Now in the broser i can see the text as `speaker-hearer's` but in the file it is coming as `speaker-hearer&#39;s`

How can i fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the browser decodes this data automatically, but the text within the file will be raw; so you are seeing the data "as it is".

Maybe you can use the HTMLParser library to decode the data generated by Django (`output`) before writing to the `abc.tex` file.

For your sample string:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
s = "speaker-hearer&#39;s"
s = h.unescape(s)
```

So then it would be just a matter of unescaping your output when you write it to a file, and probably handling the parsing exception.

[Source](http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/) (see step #3)